# Showing that $ \left( \frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3+\left( \frac{b+2c}{b+2a}\right)^3+\left( \frac{c+2a}{c+2b}\right)^3 \geq3 $

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

I would like to show that:

$$ \left( \frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3+\left( \frac{b+2c}{b+2a}\right)^3+\left( \frac{c+2a}{c+2b}\right)^3 \geq3 $$

Using AM-GM inequality:

$$ \left( \frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3+\left( \frac{b+2c}{b+2a}\right)^3+\left( \frac{c+2a}{c+2b}\right)^3 \geq3\frac{(a+2b)(b+2c)(c+2a)}{(a+2c)(b+2a)(c+2b)} $$

It suffices to show that:

$$ \frac{(a+2b)(b+2c)(c+2a)}{(a+2c)(b+2a)(c+2b)} \geq1 $$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow ab^2+bc^2+ca^2-(a^2b+b^2c+c^2a)\geq0$$

$$ \Longleftrightarrow x+y+z\geq \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$$

$$ xyz=1$$

($x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{b}{c}$, $z=\frac{c}{a}$)

How can I prove this last inequality?
Is there any simpler proof?

Comment: The last inequality can't possibly be true. If $xyz=1$, then $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{z}=1$, and the only way the inequality can hold for both $x,y,z$ and $\frac{1}{x},\frac{1}{y},\frac{1}{z}$ is if $x+y+z=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}$, which is clearly not true in general. You're going to need to start with something sharper than the AM-GM...

Answer (score 10):

I will prove that this is true for $a,b,c>0$. If they're allowed to be non-positive, there are counterexamples; e.g., $(a,b,c)=(1,0,-1)$.

Since this expression is homogeneous in $a,b,c$, we may assume without loss of generality that $a+b+c=1$. Then setting $x=c-b$, $y=a-c$, $z=b-a$ yields:
$$
\left(\frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3+\left(\frac{b+2c}{b+2a}\right)^3+\left(\frac{c+2a}{c+2b}\right)^3=\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^3 \, .
$$
But if $a,b,c$ are positive and $a+b+c=1$, then $0<a,b,c<1$, from which it follows that $-1<x,y,z<1$. As the function $f(t)=\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^3$ is concave upward on $(-1,1)$, we have:
$$
\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)^3=f(x)+f(y)+f(z) \geq 3f\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)=3f(0)=3 \, .
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: If it was concave then the inequality should not be the other way around?

Comment: @clark: Concave *up* (i.e., convex, if you prefer the concave/convex terminology to the concave up/down terminology).

Comment: I am sorry, I didnot know that. (+1)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. I can't see why the condition $a+b+c=1$ can be added.

Comment: @Chon: If $I(a,b,c)$ is the left-hand side of your inequality, then $I(\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c)=I(a,b,c)$ for all $\lambda \neq 0$. Take $\lambda=\frac{1}{a+b+c}$...

Comment: @Chon: Alternately, if you're not comfortable with redefining $a,b,c$, you could define $x=(c-b)/(a+b+c)$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$, and the rest of the proof will go through in pretty much the same way (but with slightly nastier algebra).

Comment: OK, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Or maybe just do it by Holder's Inequality?
$$\left(\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac{a+2b}{a+2c} \right)^3 \right) \left(\sum_{cyc}(a+2b)(a+2c)\right)\left(\sum_{cyc}(a+2c)\right)^2 \ge \left(\sum_{cyc}(a+2b)\right)^4$$
As $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}(a+2c) = 3(a+b+c) = \sum_{cyc}(a+2b)$, and $$\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}(a+2b)(a+2c) = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + 8(ab + bc + ca) = (a+b+c)^2 + 6(ab+bc+ca) \le 3(a+b+c)^2$$ because $3(ab + bc+ca) \le (a+b+c)^2$, hence we have that $$\sum_{cyc} \left(\frac{a+2b}{a+2c} \right)^3 \ge 3$$ which finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rijul Saini! I don't recognize Holder's inequality in your first line, could you detail the calculations?

Comment: See [Holder's Inequality](https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/H%C3%B6lder's_Inequality). There, take $\lambda_1 =\lambda_2 =\lambda_3 = 1/5, \lambda_4 = 2/5$, and raise both sides to the 5th power.

Comment: OK, thank you for the link.

Answer (score 0):

For positive variables by Holder we obtain:  $$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3=\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{cyc}1\right)^2\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3\geq\frac{1}{9}\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\right)^3$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+2b}{a+2c}\geq3$$ or$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-3a^2b+3a^2c-2abc)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2a^3-2abc+(a-b)^3)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+b+c+a-b)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2(2a+c)\geq0$$ and we are done!